# MATLAB to R: Corresponding command for ~isempty(Object) in R

Tags: r, matlab

```
 % MATLAB Code
 while ~isempty(D.f)
 .
 .
 end
```

Below is my R code, is it same or different in logic for `~isempty` part

```
 # R Code
 while (!(length(D$f) == 0)){
 .
 .
 }
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Your translation is too literal. You'll end up with extremely inefficient R code.

Answer (score 2):

In Matlab, `isempty` determines wether an array is empty or not.

```
a = [];
isempty(a)

ans = 1
```

returns true.

In R you could use `is.null()`

```
> a = c()
> is.null(a)
[1] TRUE
```

You can also use length, both Matlab and R return 0.

R:

```
> length(a)
[1] 0
```